# Prestashop component for Joomla

Tags: joomla, prestashop

Does anyone know if there is a Prestashop extension for Joomla? I have a Joomla website but my customers prefer Prestashop with Joomla. So I only want to show their products and categories from their Prestashop stores into my Joomla website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a prestashop component for Joomla.
Its new but stable. I am using it for the last two weeks and I am planning to switch all my customers from virtuemart to prestashop. Its lightyears ahead virtuemart.

The developer's url is http://prestashop-joomla.com

If you would like to view their online demo you can take a look at

http://prestashop-joomla.com/online-demo/

Comment: This no longer supports and redirects to iQCart, a system that is no longer PrestaShop based for ecom, but does work with Joomla